# Openshift pod complains about missing directories for image

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I tested my ApachedMQ image on Ubuntu and it works fine with Docker.
On Openshift deploying the same image does not work.
It should work out of the box, just like Ubuntu, but it always complains about missing directories in the pod, or lack of permissions on directories in the pod. Below you will see errors regarding the former.

I am using the FREE edition of Openshift online v3.x
I am only using the console to deploy from the image.
Below just a sample of the log messages when the pod is ramping up for the deployment.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/activemq/data/activemq.log (Permission denied)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory '/opt/activemq/data/kahadb'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as this image should IMO, be deployable from the console without any YAML and oc CLI necessary.
Some log trace information:
`INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/docker-java-home/jre/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: Creating pidfile /opt/activemq/data/activemq.pid
bin/activemq: 484: bin/activemq: cannot create /opt/activemq/data/activemq.pid: Permission denied
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_141 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
  Heap sizes: current=62976k  free=58714k  max=932352k
    JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/activemq/conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/activemq/tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/opt/activemq/conf:/opt/activemq/../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/opt/activemq -Dactivemq.conf=/opt/activemq/conf -Dactivemq.data=/opt/activemq/data
Extensions classpath:
  [/opt/activemq/lib,/opt/activemq/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/lib/web,/opt/activemq/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /opt/activemq/data
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/activemq/data/activemq.log (Permission denied)
...
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/activemq/data/audit.log (Permission denied)
...
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@5bcab519: startup date [Fri Mar 16 21:10:18 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
 WARN | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory '/opt/activemq/data/kahadb'
ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory '/opt/activemq/data/kahadb'
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory '/opt/activemq/data/kahadb'`

SOLVED proof::[image]

Comment: Under OpenShift your image isn't usually going to be allowed to run as ``root``, which is why you will have these issues. It is better to design your images so they don't run as ``root`` but can run as an arbitrarily assigned user ID. See guidelines in https://docs.openshift.org/latest/creating_images/guidelines.html

Comment: Thanks Graham. This seems to be the case i.e. you are correct. I forgot that in my Ubuntu test I used sudo to run my docker run command. Without the sudo it has the same permission issues as the log trace in Openshift. This of course begs the question: How to configure the pod to have the credentials that match that of the "arbitarily assigned user ID". But I guess I will find out. Many thanks.

Comment: Using ``sudo docker run`` wouldn't make a difference. It is based on whether ``USER`` was set in the ``Dockerfile``. If not set, would run as root inside container anyway.

Comment: As to running as non root, ensure read section _Support Arbitrary User IDs_ of that linked document.

Comment: Just for posterity sake, if anyone is reading these answers, if the image being used is not alterable (i.e. re-buildable, or absolutely requires root privs.) then the other less secure method would be to *Enable Images to Run with USER in the Dockerfile* here in this reference for admin for Openshift: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#enable-images-to-run-with-user-in-the-dockerfile

Comment: If only it was that simple! For the Openshift project running the command mentioned above, gives an `Error from server (Forbidden): securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io "privileged" is forbidden:` response. <br> You would have thought for a use case like this it *should* be a doddle.

Comment: I just found a reference to this issue in the Playground (OpenShift 3.7)..https://learn.openshift.com/playgrounds/openshift37/ (scroll down the left side to the bottom and you will see [Running Images as a Defined User].

Comment: *If you attempt to run an arbitrary image from an external image registry such a Docker Hub, which is not built to best practices, or requires that it be run as root, it may not work as a result.

In order to run such an image, you will need to grant additional privileges to the project you create to allow it to run an application image as any user ID. This can be done by running the command:*

`oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default -n myproject --as system:admin`

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use the Openshift playground. I am using a *Starter* instance of OpenShift. So when I run the above command it gives me the same security error and says that my user is not allowed to have these elevated rights at the cluster level.

Comment: Well, my findings continue. What I did was to use the Playground, that successfully accepts the *oc adm policy ... * command. I point to the SAME image for apacheMQ and I get the exact same missing files errors as the non-playground instance of Openshift instance I am using that DOES NOT allow the same policy change. Therefore, this cannot be the root cause. Here are some of the errors:  
  `log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/activemq/data/audit.log (Permission denied)`

Comment: Provide a link to the documentation/source of the image you are trying to use. Do the instructions for that image say you are meant to be mounting a volume into the container when being run?

Comment: Here is the repo...I was looking at the Dockerfile for some clues. https://hub.docker.com/r/rmohr/activemq/~/dockerfile/

Comment: Just added log trace info into the original question. The issue seems to be with the permissions for the $APACHEMQ_HOME/data directory not writable either by Log4J or by the persistence used by MQ. The POD fails so quickly that I am not able to go **into the container** and check things out.

Comment: I SOLVED IT>.....

Comment: I used the Playground (see above) executed all the commands including the admin rights command. Then I imported the image and I mapped ACTIVEMQ_DATA to /tmp. I then deployed and it works...just going to test the route. I will then map the data as above to my non-Playground version...and see what happens. I am chuffed to bits, I have now been trying this for 4 days.

Comment: Yep it works perfectly. The route woks...how can I paste the proof here of the url..?? I will paste it in the original question. Thanks very much for your help @Graham.

Comment: You can debug startup problems by running ``oc debug dc/yourappname``. That will give an interactive shell where you can then start up the application yourself, changing anything in the environment or writable config files first.

Comment: /tmp on the non-playground Openshift v3.7 cluster that I am using (the FREE version) defaults to Not Writeable. So, it fails there. I mean how on earth can /tmp not be writeable.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the image to successfully be deployed, the following have to be done on the cluster:

1. `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default -n myproject --as system:admin`
2. When deploying set the ACTIVEMQ_DATA environment variable to */tmp*

I will continue to find other alternatives including a rebuild of the image, creating a pod with the requisite permissions for the $APACHEMQ_DATA directory.

Below proof of the route working on the playground instance.
It is o.k. to paste it as the playground will expire in the next 10 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the image.
The docker file can be found here on my fork:
https://github.com/beezerbt/docker-activemq/tree/master/5.14.5-openshift-v3.9.14

The image for the above can be found here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/beezer/openshift-ready-mq/tags/
Tag::[5.14.5-3.9.14]

Finally, since the image has an *ephemeral* persistence, a volume can be mapped to `/app` within the openshift cluster quite easily; however do remember that you must set the volume mount point as something OTHER than /app and then further down in the volume definition on Openshift console, specify where in the container it should be mapped to...which is then /app.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a activemq image which can be deployed in Openshift
https://hub.docker.com/r/rangareddyv/activemq-openshift

Created an image with latest version of activemq and amzn-corretto-jdk-11 as bas image because openjdk has lot of CVE's and alpine does not support the jdk-11